# Navbar - how to underline or change color active link?

Tags: html, css

i have navbar. I would like underline link in menu which is active. How do that?

```css
.nav a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav a:active {
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">info</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/main">Main site</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/login">/login</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/first">/first</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/second">/second</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/third">Sport</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/fourth">fourth</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But it does not work. I search similar topics but i didn't find good solution for it.

Comment: This works? What is your exact problem, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: How you know it is the acitve ? are you adding a class ?

Comment: fwiw: this is my working example http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/WGQAxN

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will already change the active color. But I believe you're thinking of the active element of bootstrap.

The CSS **:active** selector is used when you want to change the feature of an element when you click it (can see the effect when you click and hold). In bootstrap by adding,

```
class="active"
```

The styles on the element will shift depending on what page your on. See how I modified the CSS? This will change the background of the active element for whatever page you are on.

```css
.nav a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav a:active {
  background-color: red !important;
}


/* Notice how we added an id? This let's us
   be more specific and override the bootstrap selector
*/
.navbar > #my-nav > .active > a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">info</a>
  </div>
  <ul id="my-nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"> <a href="#">Main site</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">login</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">first</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">second</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sport</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">fourth</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Side Notes** : The background won't change until you have your site up with different pages to go to. For instance you would change,

```
<li class="active"> <a href="home.html">Main site</a> </li>
```

Then whenever you clicked on it from another page, it would change the background to red.

Comment: Thank you, i used your solution but now my li"main site" (this with class active) is still with red background, does not matter is this page active or not. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used the code in an actual website? A place where when you click the link it would go to a different page? As I mentioned, it will be red until you actually switch to different pages :)

Comment: Now i have every li with class 'active' with red background. So i am on one of this sites and every other li has red background too.

Answer (score -2):

You need to work with php in order to get what you want.

first give every page a name:

```
<?php $page='home'; ?>
```

then go to your navigation and add the following to your navigation

```
 <li><a <?php if($page == 'Home') {echo 'class="active"';} ?> href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

last make a class in ur css with the name active and style it

```
.active{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

this should do the trick

Comment: Tags on the question are CSS and HTML, your answer should be limited to the topics of the question.